# Set timeout disable

Tags: jquery, settimeout, slidetoggle

I have a problem. I have this menu which dropdowns on click and I want it to go back after 5 seconds if nothing happened. I got this far. But there is this glitch that when I have clicked it to go back, it comes out after 5 sec without asking. Is it possible for it to check if it's still visible then go back, if not, keep calm and carry on?

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#aktivs-share').click(function() {     
  $('#share').slideToggle('slow', function() {  });
  setTimeout(function() {
  $('#share').slideToggle('slow', function() {  });
}, 5000);
});
 $('#aktivs').click(function() {
  $('#valodas').slideToggle('slow', function() {  });
  setTimeout(function() {
  $('#valodas').slideToggle('slow', function() {  });     
 }, 5000); 
});
});
```

Comment: try `clearTimeout()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout

Comment: Your could set a variable and then, clear it on the callback function.                                      
$('#valodas').slideToggle('slow', function() { <Here> });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of the state the menu is in, and then use clearTimeout() to clear the timeout if the state of the menu is closed.

(code is untested, but hopefully you get the idea)

```
    var shareOpen = false;
    var shareTimeoutHandle = undefined;
    $('#aktivs-share').click(function() {
        $('#share').slideToggle('slow', function() {  });

        // check the current state, if open already, close and reset
        if (shareOpen) clearTimeout(shareTimeoutHandle);
        else {
            shareTimeoutHandle = setTimeout(function() {
                $('#share').slideToggle('slow', function() {  });
            }, 5000);
        }
        // set the new state to be the opposite
        shareOpen = !shareOpen;
    });
```

Comment: +1 for the example. Note that you can combine your `shareOpen` and `shareTimeoutHandle`. `0` is not a valid timer handle, so just use 0 in `shareTimeoutHandle` as your "closed" flag, !0 means it's open. To do that, be sure to clear it when the timer fires.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the return value of `setTimeout`, it's a handle you can use to cancel it via [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout).

In your case, since you want to do it with more than one thing, probably best to store the timer handle actually *on* the element, via [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data).

You might consider writing yourself a plug-in method to do this, to avoid duplicating the logic. `slideToggleAutoClose` or something. :-)